# How to understand constructor of tf.FIFOQueue?

Tags: tensorflow

I have written some code, but I can't explain well.

The first code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.FIFOQueue(10, [tf.int32, tf.int32])
en = f.enqueue([[1,2],[3,4]])
de = f.dequeue()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    en.run()
    x = sess.run(de)
    print(x)
```

I define the element of queue is a tuple of tensor, so when I enqueue `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, it works well and the output is `[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]`.

But the second code, I can't understand.

```
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.FIFOQueue(10, [tf.int32])
en = f.enqueue([1,2,3,4])
de = f.dequeue()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    en.run()
    x = sess.run(de)
    print(x)
```

According to the first code, I think output is `[array(1, 2, 3, 4)]`, but in fact, the output is `1`. How to explain well for the second code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change arguments in enqueue operation of your second code to:

```
en = f.enqueue([[1,2,3,4]])
```

you will have results which you supposed.

You can use `shape` argument in constructor of `tf.FIFOQueue` for more definiteness. As example if you change your code as:

```
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.FIFOQueue(10, [tf.int32], shapes = [4])
en = f.enqueue([1,2,3,4])
de = f.dequeue()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    en.run()
    x = sess.run(de)
    print(x)
```

you will receive error on `f.enqueue` operation.

But if you use this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.FIFOQueue(10, [tf.int32], shapes = [4])
en = f.enqueue([[1,2,3,4]])
de = f.dequeue()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    en.run()
    x = sess.run(de)
    print(x)
```

you will have no errors.

Comment: But how to explain this? Why I need to use `[ [1,2,3,4] ]`. Like the first code, I don't use `[[[1,2],[3,4]]]`, it works well.

Comment: I not so good in English for explain this. But i will try.
You have the queue with elements. Every element is a set (or list) of Tensors. You setup `dtypes` - a list of `dtype`, one for every Tensor in the set (= element of queue). 
In your first code you enqueue element composed from 2 tensors. 
In your second code you enqueue element composed from 4 *0D* Tensors in the queue defined for contain elements composed from only one tensor. And only one *0D* tensor was added to queue.